# Как сделать круглую иконку приложения?

Tags: android, icon

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не получается изменить форму иконку приложения с квадратной на круглую.
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать

Comment: ответ - нарисовать

Comment: Должно быть 2 иконки в проекте: `ic_launcher.png` (обычная) и `ic_launcher_round.png` (круглая)

Comment: в манифесте прописано для приложения android:icon_round ?

Answer (score 1):

В [этой](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive) от статье довольно подробно все расписано.

Для круглой иконки используется `android:roundIcon`

```
<application
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ...>
</application>
```

Так же можно воспользоваться любым [android launcher icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

Answer (score 0):

сначала подготовим прозрачную PNG 512х512. потом в дереве проекта выбираем раздел Андроид. правой кнопкой создать новый файл и выбираем Image Asset. сначала сделаем адаптивную и легаси.

тут надо будет указать фон ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО! применим это все. а потом сделаем то же самое, только выберем только легаси. и параметр Shape поставим на None.
так мы сделаем прозрачную (если телефон поддерживает) иконку. если нет - есть с фоном.

Comment: Я сделал все что Вы сказали , но это не помогло(

Comment: @Noobik если Вы сделали в этой последовательности, и у вас иконка с фоном (который вы выставили сами), то скорее всего, ваш телефон не поддерживает такой формат. посмотрите иконки других приложений. если есть прозранчые/круглые и тд значки - что-то сделали неправильно. не найдете таких значков - попробуйте на другом устройстве проверить.